# Is there an owner-draw control for silverlight, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Sorry for the dumb question but I'd like to know if an ownerdrawn control can be used in a WPF or silverlight application. I never heard of one though,

Thank you,.....

Answer (score 5):

Actually the beauty of WPF is that every control is actually ownerdraw (in terms of Windows Forms development). You can do with the shape of controls whatever you want still remaining consistent in all functinality provided by him.

It's impossible in one answer to describe all potential WPF has, so I strongly suggest to find  WPF documentation and read read read...